# Highcharts renders the chart as solid black and missing 'fill' attribute on `rect`

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am trying an [example of Highcharts](http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/kh5jY/) as is it in my application. But I am getting just a solid black rectangle as shown in the following image.

[image]

The following is the output I get:

```
<div id="activity-chart" data-highcharts-chart="0" style="height: 300px;">
  <div id="highcharts-tpw9bq1-0" dir="ltr" class="highcharts-container ">
    <svg version="1.1" class="highcharts-root" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="675" height="300" viewBox="0 0 675 300">
      <desc>Created with Highcharts 6.0.4</desc>
      <defs>
        <clipPath id="highcharts-tpw9bq1-1">
          <rect x="0" y="0" width="156" height="585"></rect>
        </clipPath>
      </defs>
      <rect class="highcharts-background" x="0.5" y="0.5" width="673" height="298" rx="0" ry="0"></rect>
      <rect class="highcharts-plot-background" x="80" y="42" width="585" height="156"></rect>
      <g class="highcharts-grid highcharts-xaxis-grid ">
        <path class="highcharts-grid-line" d="M 80 94.5 L 665 94.5" opacity="1"></path>
        <path class="highcharts-grid-line" d="M 80 146.5 L 665 146.5" opacity="1"></path>
        <path class="highcharts-grid-line" d="M 80 198.5 L 665 198.5" opacity="1"></path>
        <path class="highcharts-grid-line" d="M 80 41.5 L 665 41.5" opacity="1"></path>
      </g>
      <g class="highcharts-grid highcharts-yaxis-grid ">
        <path class="highcharts-grid-line" d="M 79.5 42 L 79.5 198" opacity="1"></path>
        <path class="highcharts-grid-line" d="M 152.5 42 L 152.5 198" opacity="1"></path>
        <path class="highcharts-grid-line" d="M 225.5 42 L 225.5 198" opacity="1"></path>
        <path class="highcharts-grid-line" d="M 298.5 42 L 298.5 198" opacity="1"></path>
        <path class="highcharts-grid-line" d="M 372.5 42 L 372.5 198" opacity="1"></path>
        <path class="highcharts-grid-line" d="M 445.5 42 L 445.5 198" opacity="1"></path>
        <path class="highcharts-grid-line" d="M 518.5 42 L 518.5 198" opacity="1"></path>
        <path class="highcharts-grid-line" d="M 591.5 42 L 591.5 198" opacity="1"></path>
        <path class="highcharts-grid-line" d="M 665.5 42 L 665.5 198" opacity="1"></path>
      </g>
      <rect class="highcharts-plot-border" x="79.5" y="41.5" width="586" height="157"></rect>
      <g class="highcharts-axis highcharts-xaxis ">
        <path class="highcharts-axis-line" d="M 79.5 42 L 79.5 198"></path>
        <path class="highcharts-tick" d="M 80 94.5 L 70 94.5" opacity="1"></path>
        <path class="highcharts-tick" d="M 80 146.5 L 70 146.5" opacity="1"></path>
        <path class="highcharts-tick" d="M 80 198.5 L 70 198.5" opacity="1"></path>
        <path class="highcharts-tick" d="M 80 41.5 L 70 41.5" opacity="1"></path>
      </g>
      <g class="highcharts-axis highcharts-yaxis ">
        <path class="highcharts-axis-line" d="M 80 198.5 L 665 198.5"></path>
        <text x="372.5" text-anchor="middle" transform="translate(0,0)" class="highcharts-axis-title" y="242">
          <tspan>Fruit eaten</tspan>
        </text>
      </g>
      <g class="highcharts-series-group">
        <g class="highcharts-series highcharts-series-0 highcharts-bar-series highcharts-color-0 highcharts-tracker" transform="translate(665,198) rotate(90) scale(-1,1) scale(1 1)" clip-path="url(#highcharts-tpw9bq1-1)">
          <rect x="131.5" y="512.5" width="13" height="73" class="highcharts-point highcharts-color-0"></rect>
          <rect x="79.5" y="585.5" width="13" height="0" class="highcharts-point highcharts-color-0"></rect>
          <rect x="27.5" y="293.5" width="13" height="292" class="highcharts-point highcharts-color-0"></rect>
        </g>
        <g class="highcharts-markers highcharts-series-0 highcharts-bar-series highcharts-color-0 " transform="translate(665,198) rotate(90) scale(-1,1) scale(1 1)" clip-path="none"></g>
        <g class="highcharts-series highcharts-series-1 highcharts-bar-series highcharts-color-1 highcharts-tracker" transform="translate(665,198) rotate(90) scale(-1,1) scale(1 1)" clip-path="url(#highcharts-tpw9bq1-1)">
          <rect x="115.5" y="219.5" width="13" height="366" class="highcharts-point highcharts-color-1"></rect>
          <rect x="63.5" y="73.5" width="13" height="512" class="highcharts-point highcharts-color-1"></rect>
          <rect x="11.5" y="366.5" width="13" height="219" class="highcharts-point highcharts-color-1"></rect>
        </g>
        <g class="highcharts-markers highcharts-series-1 highcharts-bar-series highcharts-color-1 " transform="translate(665,198) rotate(90) scale(-1,1) scale(1 1)" clip-path="none"></g>
      </g>
      <text x="338" text-anchor="middle" class="highcharts-title" y="21">
        <tspan>Fruit Consumption</tspan>
      </text>
      <text x="338" text-anchor="middle" class="highcharts-subtitle" y="43"></text>
      <g class="highcharts-legend" transform="translate(266,257)">
        <rect class="highcharts-legend-box" rx="0" ry="0" x="0.5" y="0.5" width="141" height="27" visibility="visible"></rect>
        <g>
          <g>
            <g class="highcharts-legend-item highcharts-bar-series highcharts-color-0 highcharts-series-0" transform="translate(8,3)">
              <text x="21" text-anchor="start" y="17">
                <tspan>Jane</tspan>
              </text>
              <rect x="1" y="4" width="14" height="14" rx="7" ry="7" class="highcharts-point"></rect>
            </g>
            <g class="highcharts-legend-item highcharts-bar-series highcharts-color-1 highcharts-series-1" transform="translate(80.984375,3)">
              <text x="21" y="17" text-anchor="start">
                <tspan>John</tspan>
              </text>
              <rect x="1" y="4" width="14" height="14" rx="7" ry="7" class="highcharts-point"></rect>
            </g>
          </g>
        </g>
      </g>
      <g class="highcharts-axis-labels highcharts-xaxis-labels ">
        <text x="65" text-anchor="end" transform="translate(0,0)" y="74" opacity="1">
          <tspan>Apples</tspan>
        </text>
        <text x="65" text-anchor="end" transform="translate(0,0)" y="126" opacity="1">
          <tspan>Bananas</tspan>
        </text>
        <text x="65" text-anchor="end" transform="translate(0,0)" y="178" opacity="1">
          <tspan>Oranges</tspan>
        </text>
      </g>
      <g class="highcharts-axis-labels highcharts-yaxis-labels ">
        <text x="80" text-anchor="middle" transform="translate(0,0)" y="220" opacity="1">
          <tspan>0</tspan>
        </text>
        <text x="153.125" text-anchor="middle" transform="translate(0,0)" y="220" opacity="1">
          <tspan>1</tspan>
        </text>
        <text x="226.25" text-anchor="middle" transform="translate(0,0)" y="220" opacity="1">
          <tspan>2</tspan>
        </text>
        <text x="299.375" text-anchor="middle" transform="translate(0,0)" y="220" opacity="1">
          <tspan>3</tspan>
        </text>
        <text x="372.5" text-anchor="middle" transform="translate(0,0)" y="220" opacity="1">
          <tspan>4</tspan>
        </text>
        <text x="445.625" text-anchor="middle" transform="translate(0,0)" y="220" opacity="1">
          <tspan>5</tspan>
        </text>
        <text x="518.75" text-anchor="middle" transform="translate(0,0)" y="220" opacity="1">
          <tspan>6</tspan>
        </text>
        <text x="591.875" text-anchor="middle" transform="translate(0,0)" y="220" opacity="1">
          <tspan>7</tspan>
        </text>
        <text x="660.6953125" text-anchor="middle" transform="translate(0,0)" y="220" opacity="1">
          <tspan>8</tspan>
        </text>
      </g>
      <text x="665" class="highcharts-credits" text-anchor="end" y="295">Highcharts.com</text>
    </svg>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can notice in the above code is that not a single element have the attribute `fill`. But in the example output on JSFiddle, you can see that many elements have the attribute `fill`. You can see the output below:

```
<div id="container" style="height: 300px" data-highcharts-chart="0">
  <div id="highcharts-odm2fvi-0" dir="ltr" class="highcharts-container " style="position: relative; overflow: hidden; width: 599px; height: 300px; text-align: left; line-height: normal; z-index: 0; -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);">
    <svg version="1.1" class="highcharts-root" style="font-family:&quot;Lucida Grande&quot;, &quot;Lucida Sans Unicode&quot;, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:12px;" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="599" height="300" viewBox="0 0 599 300">
      <desc>Created with Highcharts 6.0.4</desc>
      <defs>
        <clipPath id="highcharts-odm2fvi-1">
          <rect x="0" y="0" width="160" height="519" fill="none"></rect>
        </clipPath>
      </defs>
      <rect fill="#ffffff" class="highcharts-background" x="0" y="0" width="599" height="300" rx="0" ry="0"></rect>
      <rect fill="none" class="highcharts-plot-background" x="70" y="46" width="519" height="160"></rect>
      <g class="highcharts-grid highcharts-xaxis-grid ">
        <path fill="none" class="highcharts-grid-line" d="M 70 99.5 L 589 99.5" opacity="1"></path>
        <path fill="none" class="highcharts-grid-line" d="M 70 153.5 L 589 153.5" opacity="1"></path>
        <path fill="none" class="highcharts-grid-line" d="M 70 206.5 L 589 206.5" opacity="1"></path>
        <path fill="none" class="highcharts-grid-line" d="M 70 46.5 L 589 46.5" opacity="1"></path>
      </g>
      <g class="highcharts-grid highcharts-yaxis-grid ">
        <path fill="none" stroke="#e6e6e6" stroke-width="1" class="highcharts-grid-line" d="M 69.5 46 L 69.5 206" opacity="1"></path>
        <path fill="none" stroke="#e6e6e6" stroke-width="1" class="highcharts-grid-line" d="M 134.5 46 L 134.5 206" opacity="1"></path>
        <path fill="none" stroke="#e6e6e6" stroke-width="1" class="highcharts-grid-line" d="M 199.5 46 L 199.5 206" opacity="1"></path>
        <path fill="none" stroke="#e6e6e6" stroke-width="1" class="highcharts-grid-line" d="M 264.5 46 L 264.5 206" opacity="1"></path>
        <path fill="none" stroke="#e6e6e6" stroke-width="1" class="highcharts-grid-line" d="M 329.5 46 L 329.5 206" opacity="1"></path>
        <path fill="none" stroke="#e6e6e6" stroke-width="1" class="highcharts-grid-line" d="M 393.5 46 L 393.5 206" opacity="1"></path>
        <path fill="none" stroke="#e6e6e6" stroke-width="1" class="highcharts-grid-line" d="M 458.5 46 L 458.5 206" opacity="1"></path>
        <path fill="none" stroke="#e6e6e6" stroke-width="1" class="highcharts-grid-line" d="M 523.5 46 L 523.5 206" opacity="1"></path>
        <path fill="none" stroke="#e6e6e6" stroke-width="1" class="highcharts-grid-line" d="M 589.5 46 L 589.5 206" opacity="1"></path>
      </g>
      <rect fill="none" class="highcharts-plot-border" x="70" y="46" width="519" height="160"></rect>
      <g class="highcharts-axis highcharts-xaxis ">
        <path fill="none" class="highcharts-tick" stroke="#ccd6eb" stroke-width="1" d="M 70 99.5 L 60 99.5" opacity="1"></path>
        <path fill="none" class="highcharts-tick" stroke="#ccd6eb" stroke-width="1" d="M 70 153.5 L 60 153.5" opacity="1"></path>
        <path fill="none" class="highcharts-tick" stroke="#ccd6eb" stroke-width="1" d="M 70 206.5 L 60 206.5" opacity="1"></path>
        <path fill="none" class="highcharts-tick" stroke="#ccd6eb" stroke-width="1" d="M 70 45.5 L 60 45.5" opacity="1"></path>
        <path fill="none" class="highcharts-axis-line" stroke="#ccd6eb" stroke-width="1" d="M 69.5 46 L 69.5 206"></path>
      </g>
      <g class="highcharts-axis highcharts-yaxis ">
        <text x="329.5" text-anchor="middle" transform="translate(0,0)" class="highcharts-axis-title" style="color:#666666;fill:#666666;" y="244">
          <tspan>Fruit eaten</tspan>
        </text>
        <path fill="none" class="highcharts-axis-line" d="M 70 206 L 589 206"></path>
      </g>
      <g class="highcharts-series-group">
        <g class="highcharts-series highcharts-series-0 highcharts-bar-series highcharts-color-0 highcharts-tracker " transform="translate(589,206) rotate(90) scale(-1,1) scale(1 1)" clip-path="url(#highcharts-odm2fvi-1)">
          <rect x="134.5" y="454.5" width="13" height="65" fill="rgb(124,181,236)" stroke="#ffffff" stroke-width="1" class="highcharts-point highcharts-color-0 "></rect>
          <rect x="81.5" y="519.5" width="13" height="0" fill="#7cb5ec" stroke="#ffffff" stroke-width="1" class="highcharts-point highcharts-color-0"></rect>
          <rect x="27.5" y="260.5" width="13" height="259" fill="#7cb5ec" stroke="#ffffff" stroke-width="1" class="highcharts-point highcharts-color-0"></rect>
        </g>
        <g class="highcharts-markers highcharts-series-0 highcharts-bar-series highcharts-color-0 " transform="translate(589,206) rotate(90) scale(-1,1) scale(1 1)" clip-path="none"></g>
        <g class="highcharts-series highcharts-series-1 highcharts-bar-series highcharts-color-1 highcharts-tracker" transform="translate(589,206) rotate(90) scale(-1,1) scale(1 1)" clip-path="url(#highcharts-odm2fvi-1)">
          <rect x="118.5" y="195.5" width="13" height="324" fill="#434348" stroke="#ffffff" stroke-width="1" class="highcharts-point highcharts-color-1"></rect>
          <rect x="65.5" y="65.5" width="13" height="454" fill="#434348" stroke="#ffffff" stroke-width="1" class="highcharts-point highcharts-color-1"></rect>
          <rect x="11.5" y="324.5" width="13" height="195" fill="#434348" stroke="#ffffff" stroke-width="1" class="highcharts-point highcharts-color-1"></rect>
        </g>
        <g class="highcharts-markers highcharts-series-1 highcharts-bar-series highcharts-color-1 " transform="translate(589,206) rotate(90) scale(-1,1) scale(1 1)" clip-path="none"></g>
      </g>
      <text x="300" text-anchor="middle" class="highcharts-title" style="color:#333333;font-size:18px;fill:#333333;" y="24">
        <tspan>Fruit Consumption</tspan>
      </text>
      <text x="300" text-anchor="middle" class="highcharts-subtitle" style="color:#666666;fill:#666666;" y="45"></text>
      <g class="highcharts-legend" transform="translate(232,259)">
        <rect fill="none" class="highcharts-legend-box" rx="0" ry="0" x="0" y="0" width="134" height="26" visibility="visible"></rect>
        <g>
          <g>
            <g class="highcharts-legend-item highcharts-bar-series highcharts-color-0 highcharts-series-0" transform="translate(8,3)">
              <text x="21" style="color:#333333;font-size:12px;font-weight:bold;cursor:pointer;fill:#333333;" text-anchor="start" y="15">
                <tspan>Jane</tspan>
              </text>
              <rect x="2" y="4" width="12" height="12" fill="#7cb5ec" rx="6" ry="6" class="highcharts-point"></rect>
            </g>
            <g class="highcharts-legend-item highcharts-bar-series highcharts-color-1 highcharts-series-1" transform="translate(76.390625,3)">
              <text x="21" y="15" style="color:#333333;font-size:12px;font-weight:bold;cursor:pointer;fill:#333333;" text-anchor="start">
                <tspan>John</tspan>
              </text>
              <rect x="2" y="4" width="12" height="12" fill="#434348" rx="6" ry="6" class="highcharts-point"></rect>
            </g>
          </g>
        </g>
      </g>
      <g class="highcharts-axis-labels highcharts-xaxis-labels ">
        <text x="55" style="color:#666666;cursor:default;font-size:11px;fill:#666666;" text-anchor="end" transform="translate(0,0)" y="77" opacity="1">
          <tspan>Apples</tspan>
        </text>
        <text x="55" style="color:#666666;cursor:default;font-size:11px;fill:#666666;" text-anchor="end" transform="translate(0,0)" y="131" opacity="1">
          <tspan>Bananas</tspan>
        </text>
        <text x="55" style="color:#666666;cursor:default;font-size:11px;fill:#666666;" text-anchor="end" transform="translate(0,0)" y="184" opacity="1">
          <tspan>Oranges</tspan>
        </text>
      </g>
      <g class="highcharts-axis-labels highcharts-yaxis-labels ">
        <text x="70" style="color:#666666;cursor:default;font-size:11px;fill:#666666;" text-anchor="middle" transform="translate(0,0)" y="225" opacity="1">0</text>
        <text x="134.875" style="color:#666666;cursor:default;font-size:11px;fill:#666666;" text-anchor="middle" transform="translate(0,0)" y="225" opacity="1">1</text>
        <text x="199.75" style="color:#666666;cursor:default;font-size:11px;fill:#666666;" text-anchor="middle" transform="translate(0,0)" y="225" opacity="1">2</text>
        <text x="264.625" style="color:#666666;cursor:default;font-size:11px;fill:#666666;" text-anchor="middle" transform="translate(0,0)" y="225" opacity="1">3</text>
        <text x="329.5" style="color:#666666;cursor:default;font-size:11px;fill:#666666;" text-anchor="middle" transform="translate(0,0)" y="225" opacity="1">4</text>
        <text x="394.375" style="color:#666666;cursor:default;font-size:11px;fill:#666666;" text-anchor="middle" transform="translate(0,0)" y="225" opacity="1">5</text>
        <text x="459.25" style="color:#666666;cursor:default;font-size:11px;fill:#666666;" text-anchor="middle" transform="translate(0,0)" y="225" opacity="1">6</text>
        <text x="524.125" style="color:#666666;cursor:default;font-size:11px;fill:#666666;" text-anchor="middle" transform="translate(0,0)" y="225" opacity="1">7</text>
        <text x="585.5234375" style="color:#666666;cursor:default;font-size:11px;fill:#666666;" text-anchor="middle" transform="translate(0,0)" y="225" opacity="1">8</text>
      </g>
      <text x="589" class="highcharts-credits" text-anchor="end" style="cursor:pointer;color:#999999;font-size:9px;fill:#999999;" y="295">Highcharts.com</text>
      <g class="highcharts-label highcharts-tooltip highcharts-color-0" style="cursor:default;pointer-events:none;white-space:nowrap;" transform="translate(141,-9999)" opacity="0" visibility="visible">
        <path fill="none" class="highcharts-label-box highcharts-tooltip-box" d="M 3.5 0.5 L 64.5 0.5 C 67.5 0.5 67.5 0.5 67.5 3.5 L 67.5 41.5 C 67.5 44.5 67.5 44.5 64.5 44.5 L 3.5 44.5 C 0.5 44.5 0.5 44.5 0.5 41.5 L 0.5 28 -5.5 22 0.5 16 0.5 3.5 C 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 3.5 0.5"
        isShadow="true" stroke="#000000" stroke-opacity="0.049999999999999996" stroke-width="5" transform="translate(1, 1)"></path>
        <path fill="none" class="highcharts-label-box highcharts-tooltip-box" d="M 3.5 0.5 L 64.5 0.5 C 67.5 0.5 67.5 0.5 67.5 3.5 L 67.5 41.5 C 67.5 44.5 67.5 44.5 64.5 44.5 L 3.5 44.5 C 0.5 44.5 0.5 44.5 0.5 41.5 L 0.5 28 -5.5 22 0.5 16 0.5 3.5 C 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 3.5 0.5"
        isShadow="true" stroke="#000000" stroke-opacity="0.09999999999999999" stroke-width="3" transform="translate(1, 1)"></path>
        <path fill="none" class="highcharts-label-box highcharts-tooltip-box" d="M 3.5 0.5 L 64.5 0.5 C 67.5 0.5 67.5 0.5 67.5 3.5 L 67.5 41.5 C 67.5 44.5 67.5 44.5 64.5 44.5 L 3.5 44.5 C 0.5 44.5 0.5 44.5 0.5 41.5 L 0.5 28 -5.5 22 0.5 16 0.5 3.5 C 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 3.5 0.5"
        isShadow="true" stroke="#000000" stroke-opacity="0.15" stroke-width="1" transform="translate(1, 1)"></path>
        <path fill="rgba(247,247,247,0.85)" class="highcharts-label-box highcharts-tooltip-box" d="M 3.5 0.5 L 64.5 0.5 C 67.5 0.5 67.5 0.5 67.5 3.5 L 67.5 41.5 C 67.5 44.5 67.5 44.5 64.5 44.5 L 3.5 44.5 C 0.5 44.5 0.5 44.5 0.5 41.5 L 0.5 28 -5.5 22 0.5 16 0.5 3.5 C 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 3.5 0.5"
        stroke="#7cb5ec" stroke-width="1"></path>
        <text x="8" style="font-size:12px;color:#333333;fill:#333333;" y="20">
          <tspan style="font-size: 10px">Apples</tspan>
          <tspan style="fill:#7cb5ec" x="8" dy="15">●</tspan>
          <tspan dx="0"> Jane: </tspan>
          <tspan style="font-weight:bold" dx="0">1</tspan>
        </text>
      </g>
    </svg>
  </div>
</div>
```

Why does my code miss the `fill` attribute?

I use `vue.js` in my code. So, is this the cause?

Comment: How have u used highcharts with vuejs. See this [example](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/aEKKRW) using https://github.com/weizhenye/vue-highcharts.

Comment: @Deep3015 Now I am using https://github.com/superman66/vue-highcharts and it works fine.

Answer (score 4):

You are using version of highcharts styled by css, so fill  (and other attributes) are defined by css classes.

I pasted your code to Codepen, and got black rectangle. Then I pasted contents of  https://code.highcharts.com/css/highcharts.css to css section, and there it was.

So what you need to do is make css styles available to your app.
Hope that helps.